# Can we skip rollback to specific table and roll back other tables in SQL transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Stored Proc similar to below

```
CREATE PROC Usp_InsertData(@ID INT, @Name varchar(max))
    AS
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO Employee1(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name);

    INSERT INTO Employee2(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name);

    INSERT INTO Employee3(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name);

    INSERT INTO Employee4(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name);

   COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    END CATCH
```

My requirement is, if any issue occurs then in catch rollback should get called. And this rollback should occur only on Employee2,Employee3,Employee4 skipping Employee1 table.

Finally I will have data only in Employee1 and in other rollback implemented.

Is there any way to skip particular table from Transaction Rollback

**Update 1:**

I'm calling above SP from master SP as below.So, even if Master SP transaction fails, all changes needs to be rollback except Employee1.

```
CREATE PROC Usp_MasterInsertData(@ID INT,@Name varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

EXEC Usp_InsertData @ID,@Name --In this SP, I want to skip rollback to Employee1 table.

EXEC Usp_UpdateData @ID,@Name

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION


END CATCH
```

Comment: Why do you have 4 different Employee tables?!?

Comment: I just gave them as example.Kindly consider all tables as different tables.

Comment: What about taking the first insert out of transaction?

Comment: Sort of, not really, but sort of. You can use `SAVE TRANSACTION` after the first insert to produce a savepoint, and roll back to that point. This is quite limited in its uses in general, but in this specific case it might have some application. Be aware of the [caveats surrounding it](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#SAVETRAN) before you consider using it; explicit transaction handling from client code is usually much better.

Comment: Create a trigger in first table and capture values into another table, re insert back into first one, this approach works better if you don't have huge amount of transactions. You will need to truncate child table for each trigger movement.

Comment: Split this into two transactions.  Insert into the first table in one.  Then insert into the others.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Can you provide some sample.

Comment: @Ven,Is there any other approach other than creating new tables.

Comment: How about declaring try, catch blocks for each stored proc and you can avoid the first stored proc in rollback, either ways it should get inserted into first table

Comment: @Ven, actually I have multiple tables in each SP, which needs to be rolledback.I can't skip any of SP from roll back.I want to skip only particular tables in each SP from roll back

Comment: @JeroenMostert,Can I use Save Transaction in my scenario.

Comment: "Can you provide some sample" ...what's the need? You already know how to create one transaction. Gordon's suggestion is to create two transactions, and then to move the first INSERT command into the first transaction, and leave the other 3 INSERTS in the second transaction. So it's mainly just a case of copying your code and pasting it above...surely you can manage to copy without an example?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Transaction after the First insertion like

```
 CREATE PROC Usp_InsertData(@ID INT, @Name varchar(max))
        AS


        INSERT INTO Employee1(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name); 

        BEGIN TRY  
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO Employee2(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name);

        INSERT INTO Employee3(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name);

        INSERT INTO Employee4(ID,[Name]) VALUES(@ID,@Name);

       COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        END CATCH
```